# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nested transactions are not allowed. Use commitTransaction() after each beginTransaction()

Tags: android, realm

```
public RealmList<CategoriesDto> getListOfCategories(String type){

    final RealmList<CategoriesDto> listOfCategories = new RealmList<>();

    final CategoriesDto  categoriesDto = realm.where(CategoriesDto.class).equalTo("identifier", type).findFirst();

    if (categoriesDto != null) {

        realm.beginTransaction();
            RealmResults<CategoriesDto> categories = realm.where(CategoriesDto.class).equalTo("parentId", categoriesDto.getCategoryId()).findAll();
            for (int i = 0; i < categories.size(); i++) {
                listOfCategories.add(categories.get(i));
            }
        //  realm.commitTransaction();
    }

    return listOfCategories;
}
```

I'm querying realm two times in a method, and getting this error, I have tried `realm.beginTransaction()` and `realm.commitTransaction()` after each and every query.

One more thing: this query only reads data from realm db.

Ror writing data in database we generally use commit to persist data.

I have tried `realm.commitTransaction()` also but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I don't know anything about Realm. Is it really needed to call beginTransaction() before read query?

Comment: Yes , if you didn't call then too application crashes and the error is "you need to call reaml.beginTransactio()"

Comment: Have you tried adding `beginTransaction` and `commitTransaction` inside for loop?

Comment: @Sagar we are quering the realm outside the forloop , how come we can beginTransaction()  and commitTransaction() in side the foorloop , 
and if i un comment reaml.commitTransaction() then this error comes "Changing Realm data can only be done from inside a transaction."

Comment: Why do you even **need** that `RealmList`? Why not use `RealmResults`? It's also a `List`. It truly depends on your use-case, and with this amount of code, all I can say is that you're not using Realm as intended.

Comment: Oh, you would need an object link. Now I get it. Kind of.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem updating and looping an array with some RealmObjects.

I added this before the condition with the transactions

```
if(realm.isInTransaction()){
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help 
I have put my realm query lines in you given condition
if(realm.isInTransaction()){
                realm.beginTransaction();
                RealmResults<CategoriesDto> categories = realm.where(CategoriesDto.class).equalTo("parentId", categoriesDto.getCategoryId()).findAll();
                for (int i = 0; i < categories.size(); i++) {
                    listOfCategories.add(categories.get(i));
                }
                realm.commitTransaction();
            }

the if condition returns true and the debugger directly goes to realm.commitTransaction();

Comment: Your conditions must be bellow of my answer. The error is saying that you have an open realm transaction. My condition close that pending transaction. And then you open a new one.

Comment: The issue was i was trying to set the realmList that i got from query to myAdapter , by adding the realmObjects to listOfCategories ,  but the realm says , you cant use that reference if it is in transacion
and after closing that transaction too by using your condition , i was getting the same error.
so you have to use "copyFromRealm"

Answer (score 2):

Finally got the answer after a lot of try

As I was adding the realm objects by applying a for loop
instead of that I used a realm method `copyFromRealm()`, 
below is the piece of code

```
listOfCategories.addAll(realm.copyFromRealm(categories));
```

by this I think so there is no need to apply commit and begin transactions, as we are performing read operations only.

Comment: Accept your own answer, so it can help other users and keeps unanswered queue more clear.

Answer (score 1):

If at persistence time you have all the category DTOS:

```
public class CategoriesDto extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String categoryId;

    @Index
    private String identifier;

    @Index
    private String parentId;

    private CategoriesDto parent;

    //getters, setters
}
```

And then you do

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        realm.insertOrUpdate(dtos);
        RealmResults<CategoriesDto> children = realm.where(CategoriesDto.class)
                                                    .isNotNull("parentId")
                                                    .isNull("parent")
                                                    .findAll();
        for(CategoriesDto category : children) {
            CategoriesDto parent = realm.where(CategoriesDto.class).equalTo("categoryId", category.getParentId()).findFirst();
            category.setParent(category);
        }
        realm.insertOrUpdate(children);
    }
});
```

Then you can do

```
public RealmResults<CategoriesDto> getListOfCategories(String type) { 
    return realm.where(CategoriesDto.class)
                .equalTo("identifier", type)
                .equalTo("parent.categoryId", categoriesDto.getCategoryId())
                .findAll();
}
```

But in your case, you just have to not open a transaction, and use `copyFromRealm()`. In which case I'm not sure why you're using a `RealmList<T>`, though.